# Formik- how to set input field value from component's props?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am using `Formik` for my form.
One of the input is supposed to be populated by `props` value.
How can I do it?
This is my approach:

```
<input
     type="text"
     id="country"
     readOnly
     value={props.countryCode}
     // {...formik.getFieldProps("country")}
 />
```

but it is most likely interfering with `Formik` and that is why it does not work.
What is the proper solution?

Thank you!

Comment: are you importing this into another component and adding in 

<InputComponent countryside="value"/>?

Answer (score 7):

You can inject props value in initialValues.

**Set enableReinitialize to true. So Form gets re-populated when props changes.**

```
<Formik
    initialValues={{ country: props.countryCode }}
    enableReinitialize={true}
 />

 <input
     type="text"
     id="country"
     readOnly
     value={values.country}

 />
```